# What kind of access would a VPS.NET server allow me?

Tags: hosting, version-control

I am looking for a hosting server that I can do a *checkout* from a svn repository hosted somewhere else.

I also would like to be able to make changes to the `apache2/httpd.conf`

Would I be able to do this with a VPS.net hosting account (with say 1 node *to prototype with*).

If no, what is a hosting account that would allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a VPS from a place like vps.net gives you full root control. It is like having a real physical server in the room with you just without the noise.

You can login to it with SSH and what not and sudo to root or su - (depending on the OS) so what you want to do should not be a problem at all.